# Make NFS server listen only on a specific interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, nfs4, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to run a NFS server (`nfs-kernel-server` package) on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine and want to make it only acessible via VPN.

I have set the appropriate IP address in the `/etc/exports` file and my firewall.
Nevertheless, the `rpc.mountd` daemon is still listening on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0` and `::`). As a defense-in-depth measurement, I would like to restrict it further to only listen to connections on the VPN-network device.

How can I configure that?

Comment: I did not find any way to do so, however maybe you can also see here the similarly question to your one [on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210772/nfs-share-with-custom-interface)

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu and Debian have the configuration in

```
/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server
```

You can restrict it using

```
RPCNFSDOPTS="-H 10.0.40.72"
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting `nfsd(8)`:

```
OPTIONS
       -d  or  --debug
              enable logging of debugging messages

       -H  or  --host hostname
              specify a particular hostname (or address) that NFS requests will be accepted on. By default, rpc.nfsd will accept NFS requests on all known network addresses.  Note that lockd (which performs file locking services for NFS) may still accept request on all known network addresses.  This may change
              in future releases of the Linux Kernel. This option can be used multiple time to listen to more than one interface.

       -p  or  --port port
              specify a different port to listen on for NFS requests. By default, rpc.nfsd will listen on port 2049.
```

Comment: Do you also happen to know the configuration while where this can be configured?

Comment: this can be defined in **/etc/nfs.conf** file under `[nfsd]` section

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to work in Ubuntu? I found that tip in the Arch-Wiki, too, but it didn't do anything on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 22.04 (and possibly earlier), the way to do this is by dropping a configuration file in `/etc/nfs.conf.d/`:

```
# /etc/nfs.conf.d/interfaces.conf
[nfsd]
host=hostname-or-ip-to-listen-on
```

The `nfs.conf(5)` man page documents this.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the configuration in `/etc/nfs.conf` / `/etc/nfs.conf.d/*` nor the `RPCNFSDOPTS` specified in `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` affect the interfaces, on which `rpc.mountd` will listen on. So none of the other answers here actually answer the original question, which was about restricting access to `rpc.mountd` to a specific interface.

The man page of `rpc.mountd` does NOT list an option, that performs the required restriction. Instead, it recommends to use either the `tcp_wrapper` library or the kernel firewall `iptables` for that purpose.

However, with most systems having migrated already to NFS protocol version 4, there is an easier solution: NFSv4 does not need `rpc.mountd` anymore. An explanation how to do that can be found towards the bottom of this page: https://wiki.debian.org/NFSServerSetup

So, to restrict to NFS access to NFSv4 on a local interface, do the following on recent Ubuntu / Debian servers:

```
systemctl stop nfs-kernel-server.service
systemctl stop rpcbind.service
systemctl mask rpcbind.service
systemctl mask rpcbind.socket

vi /etc/default/nfs-common
    NEED_STATD="no"
    NEED_IDMAPD="yes"

vi /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server
    RPCNFSDOPTS="-H YOUR-LOCAL-IP-YOU-WANT-TO-BIND-TO -N 2 -N 3"
    RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids -N 2 -N 3"

systemctl start nfs-kernel-server.service
```

Of the four configuration options listed here (`NEED_STATD`, `NEED_IDMAPD`, `RPCNFSDOPTS` and `RPCMOUNTDOPTS`) you will find only the last one already defined in the default versions of those files as shipped with Debian or Ubuntu. Make sure to edit `RPCMOUNTDOPTS` apropriately and to add the other three. Of course, you may freely choose another editor instead of `vi`.

Before masking `rpcbind.service` with `systemctl` (which pretends, that it is started, though it is not), make sure, that no other service on your machine needs that it.